# time difference in long data format

Tags: python, datetime, time-series

I have the following issue in Python. I got some log data on funnel movements in a long data format. I have a column saying at which point of time an observation got changed into a respective funnel.

Example data:

```
idx name    changed_at  changer value
0   Comp A  25.05.2020  A   new
1   Comp B  25.05.2020  A   new
2   Comp C  25.05.2020  A   new
3   Comp A  28.05.2020  B   shortlist
4   Comp D  28.05.2020  B   new
5   Comp E  29.05.2020  B   new
6   Comp B  29.05.2020  B   long
7   Comp C  01.06.2020  A   shortlist
8   Comp A  03.06.2020  A   final
```

I would like to add another column computing the time difference to the next time the company was mentioned again such that the added column looks like this:

```
idx name    changed_at  changer value   days_in_stage
0   Comp A  25.05.2020  A   new 3
1   Comp B  25.05.2020  A   new 4
2   Comp C  25.05.2020  A   new 7
3   Comp A  28.05.2020  B   shortlist   6
4   Comp D  28.05.2020  B   new na
5   Comp E  29.05.2020  B   new na
6   Comp B  29.05.2020  B   long    na
7   Comp C  01.06.2020  A   shortlist   na
8   Comp A  03.06.2020  A   final   na
```

For example, Company A is mentioned in idx 0, 3 and 8. However, I am having issues to compute the difference to the next observation in Python on a bigger scale of 18k obeservations.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You'll need to add code to get a full answer. Assuming you have a table (list of lists) read from the csv module, you could use an dict to build a company index. The key would be company name and the value would be a list of the rows for that company. Now its just a question of processing all of those value lists... append the difference on each list and since its the same list as the original table, you're done.

Comment: You could also process this with `pandas` and `groupby`. That may be a bit of heavy lift to figure it out.At 18k data pandas may be a bit quicker in processing, but its really a tiny dataset for modern computers either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a long question which has to be broken to many parts. But I can explain the rough sudo code to you. Then u can figure out by yourself.

1. Use pandas and group the dataframe by name
2. duplicate the time col and create a sliding window to get the difference between the next date change
3. arrange back the dataframe based on the original idx